# Why is my Oracle ORDS plugin not working?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I installed Oracle ORDS (with Apache) and its working fine except for the plugins.

- When I use the plugins in Oracle Apex, its working fine, but
- when I open the ORDS, the plugins are not showing up at all, I just have an empty region.

Can anyone help with this issue?

```
GET http://ictleave:85/ords/moag1/static-files-not-configured/105/files/plugin/750188890149322211/v76/jk64reportmap.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
VM737:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: jk64reportmap_initMap is not defined
    at <anonymous>:4:1
    at r_R7869312333863101 (f?p=105:1:13096735246898::::::104)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
(anonymous) @ VM737:4
r_R7869312333863101 @ f?p=105:1:13096735246898::::::104
(anonymous) @ VM737:1
setTimeout (async)
r_R7869312333863101 @ f?p=105:1:13096735246898::::::104
(anonymous) @ f?p=105:1:13096735246898::::::105
```

Comment: When you 'open the ORDS'? What exactly does that mean?

Comment: i installed oracle 11g (apex) and have it on a server PC. However to allow end users to connect to the applications i installed the oracle rest data service(ords).

Comment: Still not clear on difference between working/non-working. Do you have any errors in browser console?

Comment: Check the browser's console (the network traffic specifically) for error messages and please post them if any.